# Ganache and webscockets

Tags: ganache, ganache-cli, websocket

I'm searching the docs, but, I cannot find anything. Does ganache support WebSocket connections? People seem to use for web socket connections in different posts.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can connect with websocket by using the RPC url, but replacing `http://` with `ws://`.

[image]

In my case (and the default), it is: `ws://127.0.0.1:7545`

Example code using ethers.js:

```
const provider = new providers.WebSocketProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:7545");
```

Comment: Great it works, thanks!
Do you know if it also supports IPC?

Comment: it does not at the moment (https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/759)